# JavaScript - Detect whether a click event triggered a DOMNodeInserted event

Tags: javascript, html, events

I'm working on a chrome extension business gamification system that tracks users across various web applications, and tracks their progress within the applications to determine a user ranking in their workplace.

I know you can track which elements are created, using something like:

```
window.addEventListener('DOMNodeInserted', function(e){
  console.log(e.target);
}, false);
```

But as this can be quite slow (noticeable lag within complex web applications), I would like to only detect elements that are created as a result of mouse clicks (on an element, for example).

I just tested this, locally:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

    <div id="creator">Click me</div>

    <script>

        var click_event = 0;

        function add_element(e)
        {
            console.log(e);
            click_event = e;
            var div = document.createElement('div');
            div.innerHTML = "created";
            document.body.appendChild(div);
        }

        function element_created(e)
        {
            console.log(e);
            if(e == click_event)
            {
                console.log("SAME EVENT");
            }
        }

        document.getElementById('creator').addEventListener('click', add_element, false);
        window.addEventListener('DOMNodeInserted', element_created, false);

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

in the hope that the events would be the same, or that upon inspecting the DOMNodeInserted event, I'd find some way of extracting the original click event from the insertion event's properties. I found nothing within the properties of the insertion event that linked it to the click event, though.

Is there any way of finding which event triggered a DOMNodeInserted event using JavaScript?

Comment: What if you add the DOM Inserted listener in an onClick listener?

Answer (score 0):

Use custom event when you are inserting elements from javascript, but only based on event "DOMNodeInserted", it impossible, still you can use a custom attribute on element `<div insertedwith="click">`  and check on `"DOMNodeInserted"` handler if `e.target` has that attribute. Anyway check the example, hope will help you.

```js
console.clear();
        function add_element_working(e)
        {
            var div = document.createElement('div');
            div.onload = function() {
  console.log("Script loaded and ready");
};
            div.innerHTML = "This is tracked with custom event";
            
            event = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
         event.initEvent("InsertedFromClick", true, true);
            
            document.body.appendChild(div);
            div.dispatchEvent(event);
        }

function add_element_notworking(e)
        {
            var div = document.createElement('div');
            div.innerHTML = "This is not tracked";
            document.body.appendChild(div);
        }

        function element_created(e)
        {
            console.log("Inserted element not knowing who trigered");
            console.log(e);
            
        }
  
     function element_created_custom(e)
        {
            console.log("Click inserted element traked");
            console.log(e);
            
        }

        document.getElementById('creator').addEventListener('click', add_element_working, false);
document.getElementById('creator2').addEventListener('click', add_element_notworking, false);
        
window.addEventListener('DOMNodeInserted', element_created, false);


window.addEventListener('InsertedFromClick', element_created_custom, false);
```

```html
<div id="creator">Click me to check that tracked</div>
<div id="creator2">Click me to check that I'm not tracked</div>
<div>HTML</div>
```